# css: expand div on hover without displacing other divs

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following code :

```
<style>
    #items {width:300px;}
    .item {width:100px;border:solid 1px #ccc;float:left;height:20px;overflow:hidden;}
    .item:hover{height:auto}
</style>

<div id="items">
    <div class="item">text 1<br>text 1<br>text 1</div>
    <div class="item">text 2<br>text 2<br>text 2</div>
    <div class="item">text 3<br>text 3<br>text 3</div>
    <div class="item">text 4<br>text 4<br>text 4</div>
    <div class="item">text 5<br>text 5<br>text 5</div>
    <div class="item">text 6<br>text 6<br>text 6</div>
    <div class="item">text 7<br>text 7<br>text 7</div>
    <div class="item">text 8<br>text 8<br>text 8</div>
    <div class="item">text 9<br>text 9<br>text 9</div>
    <div class="item">text 10<br>text 10<br>text 10</div>
</div>
```

see it in action :
http://jsfiddle.net/6K7t4/

when a div id hovered, it should expand without displacing other divs as shown at :
http://shopping.kelkoo.co.uk/ss-shirt.html

Also, please suggest how to achieve a cross-browser solution.

If it can be done using pure css, I prefer that solution.

If not, can it be done using jquery in an easy way without plugins?

Comment: http://shopping.kelkoo.co.uk/ss-shirt.html doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6K7t4/24/

HTML:

```
<div id="items">    
    <div class="item"><div class="inner">text 1<br>text 1<br>text 1</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="inner">text 2<br>text 2<br>text 2</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="inner">text 3<br>text 3<br>text 3</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="inner">text 4<br>text 4<br>text 4</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="inner">text 5<br>text 5<br>text 5</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="inner">text 6<br>text 6<br>text 6</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="inner">text 7<br>text 7<br>text 7</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="inner">text 8<br>text 8<br>text 8</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="inner">text 9<br>text 9<br>text 9</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="inner">text 10<br>text 10<br>text 10</div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#items { 
     width:300px; 
}

.item { 
    width:100px; 
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
    float:left;
    height:20px;
    z-index:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative; 
}  

.item:hover {
    overflow:visible;
    z-index:100;
}

.item:hover .inner { 
    z-index: 100;
}

.inner { 
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Each `.item` is now positioned relatively and has new child which wraps all content inside it. Once div is hovered, `.item`'s `overflow:hidden` is changed to `overflow:visible` and z-index of `.inner` is set to 100 (in order to show it above other divs).

**UPD**: New demo and updated code. For IE7 (z-index is changed for .item:hover, otherwise inner div is hidden below other `.item`s in IE7)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `child selector element` by adding another div with the class you would like to select. Here is your code updated below using it. Hope this helps!

```
<div id="items">
    <div class="item"><div class="item-extend"> 1<br>text 1<br>text 1</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="item-extend"> 2<br>text 2<br>text 2</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="item-extend"> 3<br>text 3<br>text 3</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="item-extend"> 4<br>text 4<br>text 4</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="item-extend"> 5<br>text 5<br>text 5</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="item-extend"> 6<br>text 6<br>text 6</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="item-extend"> 7<br>text 7<br>text 7</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="item-extend"> 8<br>text 8<br>text 8</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="item-extend"> 9<br>text 9<br>text 9</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="item-extend"> 10<br>text 10<br>text 10</div></div>
</div>
```

​

```
 #items {width:300px;}
.item {width:100px;border:solid 1px #ccc;float:left;height:20px;overflow:hidden;}
.item:hover >.item-extend {position:absolute;width:100px;background:#fff;}
```

You can demo the updated code here : http://jsfiddle.net/6K7t4/35/

**UPDATE:** you dont even have to use the `child selector element`, instead you can just change it on `:hover` by switching out `.item:hover >.item-extend` with `.item-extend:hover`. Works the exact same way.

Answer (score 3):

You need an extra div in order to hold an absolute-positioned one inside.

HTML

```
<div id="items">
   <div class="itemHolder"><div class="item">text 1<br>text 1<br>text 1</div></div>
</div>
```

item is absolute, and itemHolder floats.

CSS

```
#items {width:300px; padding:30px;}

// Floats and hides content with height and overflow
.itemHolder {float:left; width:100px; border:solid 1px #ccc; height:20px; overflow:hidden; position:relative;}

// Absolute
.item {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:1; width:100%; background:#FFF; border:1px solid #999; border-top:0;}

// On hover we make the overflow visible and give the div to show a higher z index
.itemHolder:hover {overflow:visible;}
.itemHolder:hover .item {z-index:2;}
```

​
Live solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/vWGCc/

:)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it with little javascript. See below,

```
$('.item').hover(function () {
    var pos = $(this).position();        
    var $clone = $(this).clone();
    $clone.appendTo(this).addClass('item_clone').css({
        left: pos.left,
        top: pos.top
    });
}, function () {
    $('.item_clone', this).remove();
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/6K7t4/32/

**Note:** Check other CSS based answers which is always better than achieving it via scripts.